# Tkinter not working on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I recently bought a new macbook pro and I've been using it to work on python. Python is already installed and the version I have is 2.7.5.

However tkinter isn't working at all on the IDLE or sublime text! I don't get an error or anything its just that nothing shows up when I enter my code!

Here's the example code I used:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep  2 2013, 05:24:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> tk = Tk()
>>> btn = Button (tk, text = "click me")
>>> btn.pack
<bound method Button.pack_configure of <Tkinter.Button instance at 0x101b4edd0>>
>>> btn.pack()
```

Edit: What I ended up doing was just downloading the python idle (version 3.3) off the internet and got the idle that came with it and now I just use that. However it's not optimized for retina at all which makes it a huge pain to use. I just use windows 7 to do it now. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: If you put that code in a file, add a call to mainloop, and then execute the file, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Strange : you have no import error and your code is ok.

Did you try it outside of IDLE or Sublime?

I tried your code from the osX terminal, it works :
An empty window appears as soon as you type tk=Tk().
Then the (second) button binding function actually modifies the window when entered.